How can I use Tailwind/Regular CSS with Wicked PDF?
So I'm new to Rails 7 and I'm trying to make a simple order management web app. I'm using Wicked PDF 2.8 (wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6) to automatically generate invoices based off of orders. The pdf is working, but the css is weird. If I use style="color:red" for example it works, but trying to use a flex container doesn't. I use tailwind for my program, but honestly even normal css would do for things like layouts.
There are a few similar questions on here but none seem to solve my issue.
I have a simple show action for my Order controller:
  def show
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    @entries = OrderToItem.where(order_id: @order)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render pdf: "#{DateTime.now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")}", template: "orders/show", layout: "show", formats: [:html]
      end
    end
  end

As well as a show.pdf.erb as a layout:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PDF Layout</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= wicked_pdf_javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_pack_tag 'tailwind', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'tailwind', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

I've tried all sorts of link_tag or pack_tag but honestly not sure what I'm to do here.
Here is my show.html.erb template:
<style>
  .flex-container {
    display: flex;
  }
</style>

<div class="flex-container"> <%# Header %>
  <div><%= image_tag image_url("logo1.png"), width: "48px", height: "48px" %></div>
  <div>street addr</div>
  <div>city, state</div>
  <div class="text-red-700">zip</div>
  <div>Date: <%= DateTime.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") %></div>
  <div>Order No: #<%= @order.id %></div>
</div>

<% @entries.each do |entry| %>
  <% @item = Item.find(entry.item_id) %>
  <div>
    <%= @item.name %> | <%= entry.amount %> x <%= number_to_currency(@item.price, unit: "$", precision: 2) %> = <%= number_to_currency(entry.amount*@item.price, unit: "$", precision: 2) %>
  </div>
  <br>
<% end %>

So I want the header to be a flex-container (im using normal css in this example) but the zipcode to be text-red-700 using Tailwind. In an html view, it looks as I expect it it, but not in the pdf view.
Any help would be appreciated. I can provide more details but honestly im not really sure what info y'all need. Appreciate it.
EDIT: According to this, WKHTMLTOPDF doesn't support flexbox nor grid

i think Bootstrap or Tailwind won't be recognized in the URL.pdf in the Wicked PDF library. You can create a CSS file and embed it into the HTML. It will work. However, please read the documentation as some tags may not be supported.
